# How can I set the date of every row in a table to the current date?

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Synonym]
(
    [SynonymId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WordFormId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Ascii]  AS (ascii([Text])) PERSISTED,
    [Text] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Version] [timestamp] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SynonymId] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

How can I set the CreatedDate to the current date for all of the rows?

Comment: why can't you update the field with GetDate()??!!

Comment: Do you mean as a default value or updating the values ??? if you mean a default use: `ALTER TABLE Synonym ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT getdate() FOR CreatedDate;`

Comment: It's a *really BAD practice* to use T-SQL *reserved keywords* like `synonym` as your database object names ..... use something more expressive, something relevant to your problem domain that **doesn't** collide with the [T-SQL reserved keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to save the date when the record was created, add a default constraint to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE [Synonym] ADD CONSTRAINT createdDate DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR  [CreatedDate]
```

Then if you insert a record you don't need to specify the createdDate and get the current date value.

If you want to set the date for all existing records simply run an update

```
UPDATE [Synonym] SET [CreatedDate] = GETDATE()
```

or for all records whose `CreatedDate` is null:

```
UPDATE [Synonym] SET [CreatedDate] = GETDATE() WHERE [CreatedDate] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Select Table Column Name where you want to get default value of current date:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name]
ADD  CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name] 
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Column_Name]
```

Alter table query:

```
Alter TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name]
(
    [PDate] [datetime] Default GetDate()
)
```

you can also do this from SSMS GUI.

1. Put your table in design view (Right click on table in object
   explorer->Design)
2. Add a column to the table (Click on the column you
       want to update if it already exists)
3. In Column Properties, enter
           (getdate()) in Default Value or Binding field as pictured below

[image: SSMS GUI]